# FAB Not Anchored Correctly - Android Design Support Lib

Tags: java, android, xml, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

Currently I have a layout that I want to center the FAB at the bottom of the layout, but instead of being anchored at the bottom, it goes past the nav buttons and only gets anchored after scrolling down on the recyclerview.

My layouts are as follows:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    android:theme="@style/Material"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/accent"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/tabs_indicator_height"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipChildren="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The fragment is inside of the viewpager and this is what happens:
[image: Broken!][image: Scroll up it's fine]

If i make the FAB a child of the Coordinator layout it works fine though...
[image]

Comment: Change  `app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"` to `app:layout_anchor="@id/list"`

Comment: I still get the same effect @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ

Comment: K i see that you are using a third party FAB..Try using google provided FAB.

Comment: I have also tried that and have had no luck with that either.